# What is tilde (~) for in R?

Tags: r, leaflet, color-ramp, function, ggplot2

I know this is an almost too simple question. But maybe there is a fast answer. Looking through some code to build a leaflet map in `R` I found that part of code:

```
mypal = colorNumeric(
  palette = "YlGnBu",
  domain = df$median
)


map<-leaflet() %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  setView(myLNG, myLAT, zoom = 12) %>%
  addMarkers(lat=lat, lng=lng) %>%
  addPolygons(data = df, 
              fillColor = ~mypal(median), ...
```

What is the "meaning" of the `~` before `mypal` in the last row. In `R` I see so many tildes that they kind of scare me as I don't know what they really mean...

Comment: I think this is a pure R question that should be researched at [so] rather than asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976331/use-of-tilde-in-r-programming-language/14976479